# how to call a function having pointers as arguments

Tags: c

I am trying to  call a function

```
Int db5_disk_header(struct db5_raw_internal *rip, const unsigned. char *cp)
{
   fprintf(openfile, "these are headers a as %d b as %d c as %d", rip->a, rip->b, rip->c);
   ...
}
```

How I call this function in main() in C?

Comment: Any good C programming book would explain how to do this.

Comment: You would start by getting rid of syntax errors. `Int` looks suspicious, just like `const unsigned. char`.

Comment: You have an extra `.` there next to the `unsigned`.

Comment: Like any other function, except for the parameters are not ints or floats or chars, but pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [Basic Pointer Operations](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10a.html)

In this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct db5_raw_internal {
    int a, b, c;
};

int db5_disk_header(struct db5_raw_internal *rip)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "these are headers a as %d b as %d c as %d", rip->a, rip->b, rip->c);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct db5_raw_internal x = {1, 2, 3};
    db5_disk_header(&x); // pointer to x using the address-of operator (&)

    struct db5_raw_internal *y = &x;
    db5_disk_header(y); // y is already pointer (don't use &)

    return 0;
}
```